# How do I prevent streaming audio through to the client in an RDP server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop

I have an RDP server than one of our clients is using.  Apparently, some users have been trying to play music on the server.  It's no surprise they are complaining about the sound quality.

So I would like to turn this off to maintain performance for other users.

Where do I set this?  is there a way to do it without hacking into the registry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start > Programs > Administrative Tools > Terminal Server Configuration:

Right-click on the RDP-TCP connection > Properties:

Client settings tab > Disable the following: check the Audio box.

If it is dimmed, this means it is set through group policy, and would need to be changed using gpmc.msc.

Answer (score 0):

The windows RDP client (mstsc) has the ability to bring audio over from the remote host.  I assume untoggling that setting in the configuration would stop this behavior.  I also assume you could make the same change in the registry or at the least script the change.  I cannot test this theory because I use linux.

Comment: It's the server end I want to control this on